# Embedding fonts in PDF

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I coauthored a book that I want to publish in India. The Indian publisher said "some of the fonts are not embedded in the PDF file shared". They sent me a screenshot of the problematic fonts (**Item 1**).

The book pdf is created with pdflatex (version info in **Item 2**).

I created a minimum working example (listing is **Item 3**, screenshot is **Item 4**).

The Linux pdffonts command run on my MWE, as well as the book seems to indicate that the fonts are embedded (**Item 5**).

`pdftexDownloadBase14 true` is set in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`

My question is - is there a problem with my pdf? Specifically, does Acrobat seem to say that the font is not embedded (which I take `encoding: custom` to mean), while `pdftools` says it is?

The font issue must be related to the fact that I'm using packages like `skull` (see MWE) and `clock`. The book itself has a large number of fonts (28 Type 1) and (10 Type 3) - `pdffonts` shows all the Type 3 fonts show as embedded (like Item 5 below) and all being with `[none]` for the name - can anyone tell me if this is significant?

**Item 1**:  Pothi's feedback

[image: Feedback]

**Item 2**: Tex Version

> [adnan@Adnans-Mac-mini]/Users/adnanaziz 1333 pdflatex --version
>
> pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)

**Item 3**: Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{skull}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Hello World. $\skull$
\end{document}
```

**Item 4**: Acrobat screenshot of MWE:

[image: skull]

**Item 5**: pdffonts ouput on MWE:

> name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
>
> ---
>
> LAGHAY+CMR10                         Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
>
> [none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       5  0

Comment: I think that the problem is not that these fonts are "not embedded" (I think they are!) but instead that they are `Type3`, which usually means "bitmapped", and thus low quality for printing in high resolution (although this depends on the resolution at which the fonts were rendered when created).

Comment: It cannot be from the external picture because the MWE exhibits it, and the MWE is trivial (not including any picture).

Comment: [`Skull` seems to be available only as metafont](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/skull) so there is nothing you can easily do to prevent the bitmap font in your pdf. The symbols itself (as a bitmap) should be included, though.

Comment: I believe sebschub has identified the issue correctly. Now I am trying to design my own Type 1 skull font and embed it. Alternately, I'll see if I can get get an existing Type 1 skull symbol from a font family. They seem to be out there (e.g., http://www.fontspace.com/category/skull), I just need to figure out how to use them with LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

[To get it off the unanswered list]

The file here uses the [`skull`](http://ctan.org/pkg/skull) package, which uses a font that is only available in bitmap format. This *is* embedded, but will not scale: depending on the resolution of the font this may lead to low-resolution output. The only way around this is to change to a different, vector, font.