# Embed (or remove) T3 fonts when creating PDF

Tags: fonts, pdftex, winedt

My printing company is complaining about some T3 fonts in a PDF I created (using "PDFTextify" in WinEDT). The image below shows how Acrobat DC reports these fonts:

[image]

Running the "pdffonts" command on my PDF prints many entries for these fonts (apparently they are embedded):

```
name    type encoding emb sub uni
[none]  T3   Custom   yes no  no 
[none]  T3   Custom   yes no  no 
... 
[none]  T3   Custom   yes no  no
```

If the fonts ARE EMBEDDED but are bitmats (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96254/embedding-fonts-in-pdf)), how can I detect which package / instances are the offending ones, so that I can try change them to use other fonts?

Thanks, Jorge.

**FINAL UPDATE:** I found the culprits! I have stand-alone-generated tables that use the `siunitx` package, and (by default?) it was using bitmap fonts for some greek letters! Adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` as advised [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4922/why-do-some-fonts-used-by-siunitx-and-textcomp-look-rasterized) replaced these fonts and solved the issue. Cased closed, thanks so much everyone for your help!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\SI{8.8}{\micro\meter}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Outputs without `\usepackage{lmodern}`:**

[image]

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
PEJPSC+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
CUJHND+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       6  0
```

**Outputs with `\usepackage{lmodern}`:**

[image]

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JQGWLD+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
DGEJQT+LMMathItalic10-Regular        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
JQGWLD+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
```

Comment: Well, you can check if the fonts that you load have type 1 versions, for instance. Can you post the list of fonts you use?

Comment: Look at the end of the log-file of pdflatex. It will tell you which fonts are included and which are bitmap (pk) fonts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Bernard. I've added the full list of fonts. The offending ones have "none" as name :\

Comment: @dontpanic That's why Ulrike asked you to look in the log file.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where is the pdflatex log located? I see some font-related messages in the main log ("my_document.log" file), should I post those?

Comment: At the end of the log is a list with pk and pfb names. Show this.

Comment: Found them! (see updated post). I just see .pfb entries though, not .pk

Comment: @dontpanic That doesn't correspond to the list produced by `pdffonts`: where are Arial and Helvetica?

Comment: Are you embedding pdf graphics in your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: no embedded PDFs in the document, all the graphics are .EPS files

Comment: if you are using pdflatex it will convert the eps to pdf before including them. Use \usepackage[draft]{graphicx} to prevent the loading of images, compile and check if the type3 fonts are still there.

Comment: @all: I have included all the lines of my main compilation log that feature the word "font"... does something strange pops out?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't explicitly instantiate graphicx in my code, as it was clashing with some other package that also instantiated it, but now I don't remember which (probably multicol) Is there a way to brute-force pass the "draft" option to graphicx somewhere in my code?

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}` early enough (e.g. before documentclass).

Comment: Great! The PDF produced in draft mode does not have the offending fonts! How can I determine which are the figures with the offending fonts?

Comment: You'll probably have to try them one by one. I've make a new doc, with the same preamble, and just the figures. Then run them one by one and examine the fonts list. (if there are many images, I'd write a programme to do it)

Comment: Thanks everyone; I found the culprits and a solution!  I however think this question shouldn't be flagged as "duplicate"; comparing the root of the problem (`siunitx`) and the solution, I think they are not really the same.