# Embedded fonts using texniccenter

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, embedding

I have to submit a pdf generated with LaTeX, and one requirement is that the fonts are embedded. The instructions I got are "At the terminal/command prompt, issue the command pdflatex filename.tex to generate filename.pdf."
I use MiKTeX, and Texniccenter for my editor. I never used a terminal or command prompt, I am not sure what this instruction means.
What I can tell is that

My output profile in Texniccenter is: LaTeX => PS => PDF

When I check the properties of the generated PDF, in the fonts tab, all the fonts seem to be embedded except one, which is called T3Font_0

Any suggestion?

Comment: `LaTeX => PS => PDF` is certainly not pdflatex, look up the profile definitions which one calls pdflatex. If your miktex is up-to-date all fonts should be embedded by default. If you think one is missing you will have to make an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also check this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/487346/120578

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. I updated Miktex and used pdflatex, and used the lmodern package but I still had T3Font_0 which was not embedded.
I ended up finding what was the problem:
I compiled chapter by chapter to see when I was getting the T3Font. It appeared that it came from a .eps figure for some reason (all the previous .eps figures were totally fine). This was the only .eps I had not made, there were no special characters (using psfrag it is included like that):

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psfrag{s}[][]{$S$}
\psfrag{y}[][]{$y$}
\psfrag{u}[][]{$u$}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Dblabla}
\caption{blablabla}
\label{fig:blabla}
\end{figure}
```

So I drew the figure on inkscape by myself and replaced the old one, and now it works!